# Add column to pandas DF using sumifs

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Im trying to add a column to my dataframe that would be doing the equivalent of a SUMIFs in Excel. I would like to avoid doing this with a groupby and then merge if possible.  I am trying to group on two columns "manager" and "product" and then sum a "value" field.  I thought i would be able to do this with groupby and then transform but when i add the second column it returns all nans.

This is my code.

```
df["mgr_prod_net"] = df.groupby(["manager", "product"])["value"].transform("sum")
```

How can I get this to work as a one liner?

Comment: Please include your sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Let do `agg` then `merge` back , since the `transform` only take one column each time

```
s=df.groupby(["manager", "product"]).agg(mgr_prod_net = ('value', 'sum'), Sum = ('value', 'sum'))
df=df.merge(s.reset_index(),how='left')
```

Comment: thanks - can you clarify what the second param in agg is for?  It seems the first (mgr_prod_net=("value", "sum") would be enough.  Also since i was planning on doing this within a method chain i was hoping i wouldnt need to make another variable.  but i guess i could define a function to do this and use pipe.

Comment: @matthewmturner newname= (original value, apply function )

Comment: understood. so you dont think this is doable in a one liner / without merging?

Comment: @matthewmturner we can do it one line even with merge , however, you still merge

Comment: basically putting the whole groupby/agg into the merge method?

Comment: @matthewmturner that is correct , but in order to make your code more clear , it is better split them to two steps

Comment: yes understood on that - i was hoping there was a clean one liner to do the sumifs without merging since it will be in a method chain. but i can just create a function and use it with pipe. not ideal but it will work.  thx.